# Updating XML file c#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I want to replace a xml node that is not a child of the root element. 
how can I do it?

Comment: *"... xml node that is not a child of the root element"*, ... so, you mean the root element ?!?!?

Comment: The question is unclear. Every node besides root is somehow a child node. You mean to skip only direct childes and update other. Please provide more details.

Comment: I'm not sure .Net implements a ReplaceEtherealNode method.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the XML you're trying to replace?

Answer (score 2):

If you use .Net 3.5 you can use System.Xml.Linq:

```
XDocument x = XDocument.Load("filename.xml");
x.Root.GetElement("ElementName").SetValue("value");
x.Save("filename.xml");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the XmlDocument.ImportNode, and XmlElement.AppendChild to do this.

```
public void AppendNodeToTarget(XmlElement targetElement, 
    XmlDocument targetDocument, XmlNode node)
{
    XmlNode nodeToAppend = targetDocument.ImportNode(node, true);
    targetElement.AppendChild(nodeToAppend);
}
```